# Installing Windows Phone app with MDM

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, mdm

I have a windows phone 8.1 app.
My app is generating is Appxbundle file.

Now i want to give my application to enterprise's MDM solution like Maas360.
What else do i need to do ? ...Will the MDM solution take it from here, sign it with their certificate and distribute ?
I don't have any options to sign from developer end.

Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

The customer needs to register for enterprise app distribution with Microsoft. They would then get Symantec certificate and you will sign the app with it.
After that the devices enrolled with MDM solution and the relevant enrollment token should be able to get your app.

Answer (score -1):

You cant insatll your windows phone 8.1 application externaly .

Comment: have you checked my questions on signing ?